# quadratic formula program trouble

Tags: ti-basic

So I made this program to solve the quadratic formula. This program also displays the discriminant of the quadratic formula. the formula is this **(-B ± √(B^2 -4AC))/2A** and the discriminant is **B^2 -4AC**. For some reason, the program only will spit out the correct answers when A is 1. There are no syntax errors that will prevent the code from running. Can I have a fresh set of eyes look at it?

```
Prompt A
Prompt B
Prompt C
(B)²-4AC→Z


(­B-√(Z))→Y
(­B+√(Z))→X

Disp "DISCRIMINANT"

Disp Z

Disp "X: "
(X)/2*A→D
(Y)/2*A→E
Disp D,E
```

Comment: is this the full thing? Where are you setting a,b and c? whats the purpose of this? what have you tried? please provide more detail!

Comment: @Baby_Boy - In TI-Basic "Prompt" gets user input and sets a variable. The code provided here seems reasonably clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues with your code.

1. You're using `B`, not `-B`
2. You're doing `/2*A`, not `/(2*A)`. The ti83/84 family of calculators evaluates multiplication and division strictly from left to right. So `/2*A` is "divide by two, *then* multiply by A".

I would cleanup your code as follows:

```
Prompt A,B,C
B²-4AC→Z
Disp "DISCRIMINANT:", Z

-B-√(Z)→Y
-­B+√(Z)→X
X/(2A)→D
Y/(2A)→E
Disp  "X:",D,E
```